# SQL Oracle fusion lines with same id

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is a simplification of my problem:

```
SELECT 123 id, 1 toto , NULL titi FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 123 id, null toto , 2 titi FROM dual
->
ID |TOTO|TITI|
---+----+----+
123|   1|    |
123|    |   2|
```

I would like to have a result like this (keeping those 2 selects):

```
ID |TOTO|TITI|
---+----+----+
123|   1|  2 |
```

Not sure how to fusion those 2 lines

One ugly solution is:

```
SELECT id, min (toto), min(titi)
FROM (
SELECT 123 id, 1 toto , NULL titi FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 123 id, null toto , 2 titi FROM dual
)
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Use Aggregation with `MAX()` to flatten the result .

Comment: yes, thank you its working!!! I edited my question as an 'ugly' solution (no offense, just to see if someone can propose something more elegant).

Comment: łWhat happens if two rows have non-null values for the same column? Which one wins?

Comment: @TheImpaler it cannot happened in my use case. But in another case, it would be problematic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it looks like a join with nvl for me:

```sql
with
 t1 as (SELECT 123 id, 1 toto , NULL titi FROM dual)
,t2 as (SELECT 123 id, null toto , 2 titi FROM dual)
select
   nvl(t1.id  , t2.id   ) id
  ,nvl(t1.toto, t2.toto ) toto
  ,nvl(t1.titi, t2.titi ) titi
from t1 full outer join t2
  on t1.id=t2.id
```

I'm not sure about your data, so probably it should be just left/right join or even inner join.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, min (toto), min(titi)
FROM (
SELECT 123 id, 1 toto , NULL titi FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 123 id, null toto , 2 titi FROM dual
)
GROUP BY id
```